# C++ MFC CTabCtrl items Debug Assertion Failure winocc.cpp SetWindowPos after insertion succeeded

Tags: c++, mfc

**The method called in OnInitDialog:**

```
void ChookDlg::add_tab_items()
    {
        tab_item_ptrs.push_back( tab_item_ptr( new CTabSLSensor ) );
        tab_item_ptrs.push_back( tab_item_ptr(new user_dlg) );
        tab_item_ptrs.push_back( tab_item_ptr( new admin_dlg ) );
        for ( auto tab_item_res_id = first_tab_item_res_id, idx = 0U; tab_item_res_id != last_tab_item_res_id + 1; ++tab_item_res_id, ++idx )
        {
            ASSERT(tab_item_ptrs.at(idx)->Create(tab_item_res_id, this)); // calls OnInitDialog
            tab_item_ptrs.at(idx)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

            mapped_tab_items[static_cast< tab_item >(idx)] = 
                tab_item_image_container( 
                                            tab.InsertItem(tab.GetItemCount(), _T("SL Sensor"), tab_item_ptrs.back().get()),
                                            tab_item_ptrs.at(idx)
                                        );

        }
    }
```

tab is an objec of type CMyTabCtrl which inherits CTabCtrl.
**Here is the Insert method:**

```
LONG CMyTabCtrl::InsertItem(int nItem, LPCTSTR lpszItem, CMyTabCtrlTab *myTabCtrlTab)
{
    UINT mask = TCIF_PARAM;
    LPARAM lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(myTabCtrlTab);

    if (NULL != lpszItem) {
        mask |= TCIF_TEXT;
    }
    ASSERT(myTabCtrlTab != NULL);
    LONG retval = CTabCtrl::InsertItem(mask, nItem, lpszItem, 0, lParam);
    if (retval < 0)
        return retval;

    CRect windowRect;
    GetWindowRect(&windowRect);
    AdjustRect(FALSE, &windowRect);
    // The left border is 3 pixel, the bottom border 2 pixel and the right border 1 pixel
    // Adjust to 1 pixel at each side.
    // windowRect.left -= 2;
    // windowRect.bottom += 1;
    GetParent()->ScreenToClient(&windowRect);
    myTabCtrlTab->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, windowRect.left, windowRect.top, windowRect.Width(), windowRect.Height(), SWP_HIDEWINDOW);

    return retval;
}
```

**Debug Assertion Failure is raised in winocc.cpp on the line 318:**

```
BOOL CWnd::SetWindowPos(const CWnd* pWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx,
    int cy, UINT nFlags)
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));
```

Templates are set correctly.

**Here's the OnInitDialog:**

```
BOOL ChookDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);
    ASSERT((IDM_RECONNECT & 0xFFF0) == IDM_RECONNECT);
    ASSERT(IDM_RECONNECT < 0xF000);
    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        CString strReconnectMenu;
        bNameValid = strReconnectMenu.LoadString(IDS_RECONNECT);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_RECONNECT, strReconnectMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // initialize tab item pointers container
    add_tab_items();
    tab.ChangeTab( static_cast< int >( tab_item::sensor ) );

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

**tab declaration:**

```
private:
CMyTabCtrl tab;
```

Comment: So which is it, invalid window handle or NULL m_pCtrlSite ?

Comment: m_hWnd should be the parent handle, m_pCtrlSite should be the tab item handle. If this is correct, then dialog should be valid (when all the lines in add_tab_items() are commented, the dialog is shown with empty tab.

Comment: Just wondering how you defined the `tab` variable in your `ChookDlg` Have you used `SubclassDlgItem' for this control, or DDE?

Comment: What does the debugger say? One of them isn't valid, the debugger will tell you which one if you add it to the watch window and step through the code to the Assert failure.

Comment: +  myTabCtrlTab 0x0145ee10 {hWnd=0x00000000 {unused=??? }} CMyTabCtrlTab *
It's the data after entry to InsertItem

Comment: In SetWindowPos: +  m_hWnd 0x00000000 {unused=??? } HWND__ *
+  m_pCtrlSite 0x00000000 {m_pCtrlCont=??? m_hWnd=??? m_pWndCtrl=??? ...} COleControlSite *

Comment: John, you have not replied on my question. It is important: Have you used `SubclassDlgItem` for this control, or DDE? In case of the former: make sure you call SubclassDlgItem before your add_tab_items in OnInitDialog

Comment: The information is updated. Up.

Comment: So, it is via DDE/DDX. Do you have   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MY_TAB, tab); in your ChookDlg::DoDataExchange() method?

Comment: void ChookDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
 CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
 DDX_Control(pDX, canvas, tab); 
}

Comment: How is your `canvas` defined?

Comment: So, in the resource for the ChookDlg's window, the tab control has this ID? So it is just `canvas` in the dialog?

Comment: There's IDD_HOOK_DIALOG in which the tab control is included with the id name canvas. resource.h defines canvas 90 and IDD_HOOK_DIALOG 170

Comment: It is very strange. I know it sounds stupid, but try to replace it to SubclassDlgItem. Comment your DDX_Control line in DoDataExchange, and add these lines to OnInitDialog  before add_tab_items():   CWnd * pWnd = STATIC_DOWNCAST(CWnd, this);
  tab.SubclassDlgItem(canvas, pWnd);

Comment: Have you checked the return value of SubclassDlgItem? It should be not zero. BTW, How did you create the Dialog? Did you use CHookDlg dlg; dlg.DoModal()?

Comment: The returned value is 1. dlg.DoModal()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code

```
tab.InsertItem(tab.GetItemCount(), _T("SL Sensor"), tab_item_ptrs.back().get())
```

the not initialized dialog pointer is taken. It should be of the form

```
tab.InsertItem(tab.GetItemCount(), _T("SL Sensor"), tab_item_ptrs.at(idx).get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this because MFC was a life-time ago but instinct tells me the line below is suspect
GetParent()->ScreenToClient(&windowRect);

Should be calling GetClientRect instead of ScreenToClient.

Comment: where is &wndTop parameter to SetWindowPos coming from? I dont see it declared or initialised.

Comment: afxwin.h static AFX_DATA const CWnd wndTop; // SetWindowPos's pWndInsertAfter

Comment: BTW, technically you should write `CWnd::wndTop`